# ACH FundAmerica implementation in PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment

Anybody having experience with ACH fundamerica API ...
I want my user to invest through ACH fundamerica payment api .

But some thing messing .

Can any one please clear the steps which I need to follow .

Thank you